# Wordress Front-end post category array

Tags: wordpress, forms, post, tags, categories

I have been trying to build a front-end form to wordpress post. I am using a custom post type but not a custom taxonomy, and these works fine.

I am doing this with the wp_insert_post function, trying to post the title, post content, Letting the user choose between 7 specific categories and let them choose ou create max 5 tags. The title and post content works fine, but I can't post the categories neither the tags.

I already tried to create an array in *post_category* and *category_name*, with the specifics ID's and/or slugs and insert on form, but with no success.

This is the custom post type on functions.php:

```
function custom_post_type_historia() {
    register_post_type('historia', array(
        'label' => 'Histórias',
        'description' => 'Histórias',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'historia', 'with_front' => true),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'page-attributes','post-formats'),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','category'),

        'labels' => array (
            'name' => 'Histórias',
            'singular_name' => 'História',
            'menu_name' => 'Histórias',
            'add_new' => 'Adicionar Nova',
            'add_new_item' => 'Adicionar Novo História',
            'edit' => 'Editar',
            'edit_item' => 'Editar História',
            'new_item' => 'Nova História',
            'view' => 'Ver História',
            'view_item' => 'Ver História',
            'search_items' => 'Procurar Histórias',
            'not_found' => 'Nenhuma História Encontrado',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nenhuma História Encontrado no Lixo',
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'custom_post_type_historia');
```

This is my php:

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

global $user_ID;

$insert_post = array(
    'post_title' => $_POST['post_title'],
    'post_content' => $_POST['post'],
    'post_status' => 'pending',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'historia',
    // 'category_name' => array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7")
    'post_category' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
    'post_tag' => $_POST['post_tag']
);

wp_insert_post($insert_post);

  }

?>
```

This is the form:

```
<form action="" method="post">


<table border="1" width="200">
    <tr>
      <td><label for="post_title">Post Title</label></td>
      <td><input name="post_title" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="post">Post</label></td>
      <td><input name="post" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="post_tag">tag</label></td>
      <td><input name="post_tag" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="post_category">Q</label></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="category_name[7]" value="7" id="category" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Apreciate all the help

Comment: You can try that by using post meta.

Comment: The category with ID 7 is already in the database? `wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=category&tag_ID=7` does that return a category?  If not, you have to first create the term by using `wp_insert_term`. If the categories have already been created in the database I would first use `wp_insert_post` without the `post_category` then use `wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'category' );` where `$post_id` will be the returned value of `wp_insert_post`

Comment: The ID 7 is a valid category, and when I tried to pass with the ´wp_select_object_terms´, the post selects all the categories in the array, ignoring my selecion on the input tag. I found [this](https://gist.github.com/clarklab/2785024) and i was able to select the category using ´'post_category' => array('0' => $_POST['cat']),´, but it only sent one category at a time @Omar-tanti

Comment: I think i am doing something wrong. I couldn't post the categories with post meta, since the array selector on the form didn't work @tristup.

Comment: I would first change the name of the checkbox input to `category_name[]` instead of `category_name[7]`.  Then before calling the `wp_insert_post` function you do `$post_category = []; foreach($_POST['category_name'] as $category_id){ $post_category[] = $category_id;}` Then in `wp_insert_post` you set `'post_category' => $post_category`. If it works I will add it as an answer.